# Spring boot always shows lazy loaded fields as null in json

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I lazy load a bunch of fields in my classes. However, these fields are null when returning the object in a request even when they should have a value.

I added the hibernate aware object mapper to my application

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder configureObjectMapper() {
  return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
    .modulesToInstall(Hibernate4Module.class);
}
```

I can access the lazy loaded fields fine when accessing them in code, but simply converting an object to json won't work.

**MediaContent.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class MediaContent extends Content {

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private StoredFile previewFile;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private StoredFile imageFile;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "downloadFor")
  private List<StoredFile> downloadFiles;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Genre genre;

  ...
}
```

**ContentController.java**
This returns the object with all lazy loaded fields `null`, even when they have a value in the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional
public @ResponseBody
Content find(@PathVariable Long id) {
  return em.find(Content.class, id);
}
```

Basically, I want the lazy loaded fields to receive their value when returning the object to a request.